Is there a way to sort a single member variable in a collection of structs using the C++ standard library?
Let's say I have a vector of a very simple struct:
struct SimpleStruct { int a; int b; int c; };
std::vector<SimpleStruct> vs;

I wish to sort this struct by 'a' leaving the positions of 'b' and 'c' unchanged.  Essentially pivoting on a, sorting by a, and then unpivoting.  As an example:
before: {1, 10, 11}, { 5, 100, 111}, {3, 1000, 1111}
after: {1, 10, 11}, {3, 100, 111}, {5, 1000, 1111} //'a' is now sorted, 'b' and 'c' relative position unchanged

If I only cared about correctness and wanted to minimize the amount of potential errors, using the standard library, the obvious solution is to create a second collection of type {value, index}, sort by value, and then overwrite the value at the corresponding index.
This is incredibly inefficient, since conceptually all we really need is a standard sorting operation with a custom comparison and a custom swap.
Is there a way to do this in C++ using the standard library without creating a custom sort method?
C++20 preferred, preferably without the use of Ranges.

@康桓瑋 I'd be interested in seeing a ranges solution.  It's just given past experience with early builds of gcc that supported ranges it would absolutely blow up compile times and produce some pretty inefficient code.  I realize years later the situation might be different but I don't know if I'd fully trust it yet.

I suggest you benchmark what you have now to decide whether it is fast enough for the actual application. There is generally no need to make everything optimal.

Given your requirement, the approach you considered (and discarded) of creating and sorting a second set {value, index} is probably best in terms of efficiency.   I suggest doing appropriate measurements/benchmarking before discarding that option out of hand.  Notionally [I don't advise this] you could give SimpleStruct a custom operator=() and use comparator that only affect the member a, but that would produce surprises during future code maintenance if anyone (including your future self) expects assigning a SimpleStruct to assign all members.

You can achieve your goal by creating a custom iterator class that wraps std::vector<SimpleStruct>::iterator and accesses only member a and giving it to std::stable_sort(), but the amount of code required would likely be greater.

@kakkoko 's idea is probably the best, but i am wondering if overloading std::swap() would work? On the other hand, can the overloading be undone after its purpose is served.. just curious..

@user2961927 in some implementations, std::sort() (and perhaps std::stable_sort()) does not use swap function in some cases, so you may not get the desired result by tweaking on swap. (libstdc++, libc++, MSVC)

I am almost certain specific versions of libstdc++ can potentially swap elements in std::sort without using std::swap in the case of POD objects.  I am very curious why it appears that std::iter_swap(...) must be defined for the object, without actually imposing the requirement that it be used.  I will likely create a question about this after I've dug into it more.

This Q has been messing with me and I know why: you have values grouped in a structure, which implies relation, then you sort one of those values without regard to the relationship! That looks to me like a design problem. Is a related to b and c or not?

This can be done easily with the help of C++20 ranges
std::vector<SimpleStruct> vs = {{1, 10, 11}, {5, 100, 111}, {3, 1000, 1111}};
std::ranges::sort(vs | std::views::transform(&SimpleStruct::a));
// vs now becoms {1, 10, 11}, {3, 100, 111}, {5, 1000, 1111}

Demo
Note that ranges::sort(vs, {}, &SimpleStruct::a) is incorrect as the projection is only applied to comparison, so it will still sort the entire SimpleStruct object rather than SimpleStruct::a.

Nice!
Could you also better explain what's happening here? For example, why if you split out that code into
auto rs = (vs | std::views::transform(&SimpleStruct::a));
  fmt::println("{}", vs);
  fmt::println("{}", rs);
  std::ranges::sort(rs);
  fmt::println("{}", rs);

seems intuitive, but why you don't get the same output?

@Federico you do?

As the comments suggested, using iterators is more involved but a generic solution could be:
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Iter, typename MemberRef>
struct MemberIter
{
  Iter i;
  MemberIter(Iter i, MemberRef): i(i) {}
  using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
  using difftype = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using value_type = std::remove_reference<decltype(MemberRef()(*i))>::type;
  value_type& operator*() { return MemberRef()(*i); }
  value_type* operator->() { return &(MemberRef()(*i)); }
  MemberIter& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }
  MemberIter operator++(int) { MemberIter tmp = *this; ++i; return tmp; }
  MemberIter& operator--() { --i; return *this; }
  MemberIter operator--(int) { MemberIter tmp = *this; --i; return tmp; }
  MemberIter& operator+=(difftype diff) { i += diff; return *this; }
  MemberIter& operator-=(difftype diff) { i -= diff; return *this; }
  difftype operator-(const MemberIter& other) const { return i - other.i; }
  MemberIter operator+(difftype diff) const { auto p = *this; p.i = i + diff; return p; }
  MemberIter operator-(difftype diff) const { auto p = *this; p.i = i - diff; return p; }
  bool operator==(const MemberIter& other) const { return i == other.i; }
  bool operator!=(const MemberIter& other) const { return i != other.i; }
  bool operator<(const MemberIter& other) const { return i < other.i; }
  bool operator>(const MemberIter& other) const { return i > other.i; }
  bool operator<=(const MemberIter& other) const { return i <= other.i; }
  bool operator>=(const MemberIter& other) const { return i >= other.i; }
  value_type& operator[] (difftype offset) const { return MemberRef()(*(i + offset)); }
};

struct SimpleStruct { int a; double b; char c; };

int main()
{
  SimpleStruct arr[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
  {
    arr[i].a = rand() % int(1e6);
    arr[i].b = rand() / 1e6;
    arr[i].c = rand() % int(1e6);
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    std::cout << arr[i].a << "  " << arr[i].b << "  " << int(arr[i].c) << "\n";
  
  auto mf = [](auto& x)->double& { return x.b; }; // Create a lambda that returns the reference to the class member of interest.
  auto begin = MemberIter(arr, mf), end = MemberIter(arr + 10, mf);
  
  std::sort(begin, end, [](auto b1, auto b2)->bool { return b1 < b2; });
  std::stable_sort(begin, end, [](auto b1, auto b2)->bool { return b1 > b2; });
  
  std::cout << "\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    std::cout << arr[i].a << "  " << arr[i].b << "  " << int(arr[i].c) << "\n";
} 

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/hzedjaMsx
Sorting like this would probably be slower than copying the data into a new vector + sorting + copying back, but the approach can be handy when memory is scarce.
